# Decomposition of spectrum

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, banach-algebras

We know that if X is a banach space and T be an element in Banach Algebra B(X) then the union of  residual spectrum continuous spectrum and point spectrum is spectrum of Banach algebra i.e σ(T) is the disjoint union of these three sets,i.e
 $\sigma (T)=\sigma _{p}(T)\cup \sigma _{c}(T)\cup \sigma _{r}(T)$ for T in Banach Algebra
But I have no idea how to prove this disjoint decomposition.

Comment: What definition do you apply for the spectra in the case of a Banach algebra?

Comment: the definition of spectrum for bounded operators in Banach space

Comment: But you don't have an underlying Banach space your element acts on a priori..

Comment: @AlexanderFrei I edit the question now.

Comment: **Point Spectrum:** *Injectivity* fails! **Residual Spectrum:** *Injectivity* holds, *Dense Range* fails! **Continuous Spectrum:** *Injectivity* holds, *Dense Range* holds, *Closed Range* fails! **Resolvent Set:** *Injectivity* holds, *Dense Range* holds, *Closed Range* holds, *Bounded Inverse* automatic! (Closed Graph Theorem!)